# Android MVVM: How to subscribe to a network call by LiveData in ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

In **MVVM** `ViewModel` generally subscribes to network call and then inform the UI i.e. (`Activity` or `Fragment`) for updating the UI like loading, success or failure. In the case of `LiveData` inside `ViewModel`, how would you observe network call changes. For observing `LiveData` inside `ViewModel` ideally it should be lifecycle aware, how to achieve this. I am using data binding to update UI so I want to listen to results in `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Transformations.map` or `Transformations.switchMap` functions in your ViewModel https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations